# What's the best way to communicate data between java services and .net clients?

Tags: java, .net, wpf, data-binding, client-server

We have what I think is a fairly typical client/server architecture, with a frontend written in .NET, displaying data sent from a backend written in Java.

Currently, we use a custom message-based framework for transmitting data snapshots and updates down to clients. This might be upgraded; although the basic java service/.net client setup is set in stone, we want to look at replacements for the message framework, for example WPF MVVM (with an eye on Sliverlight), with databindings to java web-services, or perhaps Coherence.

I was wondering what experiences others have had with this and other approaches (obviously there's no golden bullet for all situations...).

Our requirements are that the clients can show large, frequently updating and editable datasets, primarily in grids.

**Update**
I've accepted that REST/SOAP is the standard way to do it, but I'd still be interested to hear any other approaches, especially from a performance point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web services is the most common choice:

- RESTful service - more flexible, no strictly defined schema
- SOAP service - rigid schema, less flexible

Comment: And I'd suggest your REST. It is simpler and very powerful. And we are in 21st сentury... :)

Comment: Hi I'll upvote this one, but is REST/SOAP best for large datasets? The benefit of using message or cache based approaches is that updates can be pushed from client to server, wheras I think you have to do some work to do the same thing for REST/SOAP services (polling/long-polling). Message/cache approaches can perhaps be smart about how they marshal data too, to minimize size and maximize performance? I've never used REST for this sort of thing so I'm open to suggestion...

Comment: not very! An XML snapshot of one of our medium-size datasets is 23Mb, but it has very small updates. Another weighs in at only 6Mb per snapshot but almost the entire dataset is updated every 5 seconds.

Comment: that doesn't sound too big, but it also sounds strange that you have to transfer it so often.

Comment: underlying real-time data changes trigger updates in every row of the dataset. We must transmit the whole thing because views are groupable with aggregations performed over all rows... With our custom message framework we can compress the data down to ~10% (IIRC), not sure how well that would work with REST?

Comment: You can compress rest with gzip (as a normal http request).

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), which is a good platform agnostic protocol.

Comment: +1... Since I first read about them I was hooked :)  Go Google go, another shiny project created (and intensively used) by Google :)